# Analytical solution for bound state energies of infinite well

Tags: matlab, mathematical-physics, mathematica

I am trying to find bound state energies assuming infinite potential. I have been told it can be done by analytically solving Right Hand Side and Left Hand Side of an equation such as:
$$\sqrt{E}\tan^{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{2ma^2E}{4\bar{h}}) = \sqrt{V_0-E}$$
If solved properly, it should give one curve (RHS), crossed by several LHS curves. Intersection points are the answers I am looking for. Each intersection corresponds to one n. I am wondering if it can be done by Matlab or Mathematica? Sorry if it is too basic :)
Thanks

Comment: I made an attempt to write your formula in latex. Ensure that I did not make any mistakes.

Comment: Continuing from Robert's simplified equation $x \tan x = v-x$, it's possible to show using the Lagrange inversion formula that the large solutions have a series expansion $$x = w_n + \frac{v}{2} w_n^{-1} + \frac{v^2}{4} w_n^{-2} + \frac{v^3-3v^2}{12} w_n^{-3} - \frac{3v^3}{8} w_n^{-4} + \cdots,$$ where $$w_n = \pi n-\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you're trying to solve for $E$ 
$$ E^{1/2} \tan\left(\dfrac{2ma^2 E}{\hbar}\right)^{1/2} = (V_0 - E)^{1/2}$$
there are no "analytical", i.e. closed form, solutions.  It can be solved numerically, given numerical values for the constants.  You might also put this
in non-dimensional form: if $x = 2 m a^2 E/\hbar$ and $v = 2 m a^2 V_0/\hbar$, the equation becomes
$$ x \tan(x) = v - x$$